# Modifiers cannot appear here.ts(1184) error while using getStaticProps in Nextjs app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I don't know why when I use `getStaticProps` function in my component, I get an error :
[image]

but when I place it before my component declaration function, the error goes away!!
it was written in documents that we need to place in **in the component function**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show us the full code for the `pages/characters/index.tsx` page? It looks like you're trying to export the function from _inside_ the React component - it needs to be outside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a good read of the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props), it tells you to put it outside of your component function.